# Custom ListView cell containing Multiple buttons in React-Native for Android/iPhone

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native, custom-cell

I've implemented custom ListView Cells for Android/iPhone environment with React Native. The cell contains multiple labels and buttons.

In native environment of iPhone we can use tag of the cell to identify any kind of event on the cells.

I'm trying to do the same with React-Native. But as per the properties listed for ListView and ListViewCells on official page, it looks like there is no scope of cell's tag in React-Native.

I would like to know how we can identify which cell's button is pressed in ListView as there is no such things like "tag" for ListView in React-Native.

A sample code for implementing custom cell with ListView is as below.

```
    renderRow = (rowData) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, borderWidth:2, height:100, flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:16, width:200, height:40, marginLeft:20}}>
            NAME
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{marginTop:10, height:20, width:20}}
            onPress={ () => (
              // any alert or console log
            )}
          >
            <Image 
              style={{height:20, width:20}}
              source={require('./icon/tick.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data} 
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
```